# How do I use the JSON file that I have with a list of links in it to display on a web app?

Tags: node.js, json, database, express

So I scraped links from a webpage and I have it in a JSON format. Now I want to use this data to be shown in my web app / web page. What should I use? Node.js? I'm stuck with this right now.

I'm trying to create a app that will have names of songs with a clickable link that will direct me to notes for playing that song.
I have the links of all the notes in a json file as shown below. But I don't know what step to take further to fetch these links on my webpage . What framework or tool should I be using here?

```
    [
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/YamunaiAatrile_DhaLapathi.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/YammaYamma_7AmArivu.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/YaarAndhaNilavu_Shanthi.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/WhyThisKolaveri_MooNu.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/vennilave-vennilave.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/VenmegamMuttaMutta_Guru.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/VeerapaandiKOttayile_ThirudaThiruda.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/Vedam_SalangaiOli.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/Vaseegara_Minnale.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/VaarayOVaarayO_Aadhavan.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/VaaraayoVeNNilaave_Missiamma.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/vaan-nila-nila-alla.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/VaanMegam_PunnagaiMannan.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/UyirinUyirae_KaakhaKaakha.htm"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/Uyire_Bombay.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/UravugalThodarkadhai_AvalAppadithaan.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/ThuLiThuLiThuLi_Paiyaa.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/ThenpaaNdiCheemayilae_Nayagan.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/Thenmadhurai_DharmaththinThalaivan.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/ThenkizhakkuCheemayile_KizhakkuCheemayile.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/TheeraadhaViLayaattuPiLLai_VedaaLaUlagam.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/ThamthanaNamthana_PuthiyaVArpugaL.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/telephone-manipol.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/TamizhaTamizha_ROja.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/SuttumVizhi_Ghajini.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/suthi-suthi.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/snegidhanae.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/SendhooraPoove_16Vayadhinile.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/SelfiePuLLA_Kaththi.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/SahanaSaaral_Sivaji.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/RumBumBum_MMKR.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/Rojapoo_AgniNatchathiram.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/raja-rajadhi-raja.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/RasathiOnna_VaithegiKaathirunthaaL.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/PuththamPudhuKaalai_AlaigaLOyvadhillai.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/pudhu-maappillaikku.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/pudhiya-vaanam.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/PooveSempoove_SollaThudikkudhuManasu.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/PooveIlayaPoove_KozhiKoovudhu.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/PoonthalirAada_PanneerPushPangaL.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/PoonguyilPaadinaal_Nammavar.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/Poongaatru_VettriVizha.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/PoNeePo_MooNu.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/PennallaPennalla_Uzhavan.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/PanivizhumMalarvanam_NinaivellamNithya.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/PaniVizhumIravu_MounaRagam.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/PaattuPaadavaa_ThenNilavu.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/PaarthaMudhalNaaLe_VettaiyaaduViLayaadu.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/PaarthaGnyabagam_PudhiyaParavai.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/OttagathaKattikko_Gentleman.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/OruvanOruvanMudhalaaLi_Muthu.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/OruMaalai_Ghajini.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/OoruSanam_MellaThirandhadhuKadhavu.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/OodhaaColoruRibbon_VaruthapadaadhaVaalibarSangam.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/OndraRenda_KaakhaKaakha.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/OmSivoham_NaanKadavuL.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/OhButterfly_Meera.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/NooruVarusham_Panakkaaran.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/Ninnukori_AgniNatchatiram.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/NinaivoOruParavai_SigappuRojakkaL.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/NinaithuNinaithu_7GRainbowColony.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/NenjukkuLLe_Kadal.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/NenjukkuL_VaaranamAayiram.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/NenjilNenjil_EngaeyumKaadhal.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/NenjeNenje_Ayan.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/NenjaanKoottil_Dishyum.htm"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/NeePaartha_HeyRam.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/nalam-vaazha.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/naan-paesa-ninaippadhellam.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/MundhinamPaarthene_VaaranamAayiram.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/MoongilThOttam_Kadal.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/ManramVandha_MounaRaagam.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/MannilIndha_KeladiKanmani.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/ManmadhaRaasa_ThirudaThirudi.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/ManjaLVeyyil_VettaiyaaduViLayaadu.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/MaasiMaasam_Dharmadurai.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/LoosuPenne_Vallavan.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/KodaiKaalaKaatre_PanneerPushpangal.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/KaNNumKaNNumNokia_Anniyan.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/KaNNeKalaimaane_MoonRaamPiRai.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/KangalIrandaal_Subrahmanyapuram.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/KaattuKuyilu_Thalapathi.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/KaadhalRojave_Roja.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/JananiJanani_ThaaiMookaambikai.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/IsayilThodangudhamma_HeyRam.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/Irumbile_Endiran.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/IndhaMinminikku_SigappuROjaakkaL.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/IlayaNila_PayanangaLMudivadhillai.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/ILamaiyenumPoongaatru_PagalilOarIravu.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/ILamaiIdhoIdho_SakalaKalaaVallavan.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/IdhuVarai_Goa.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/Hosanna_VinnaiThaandiVaruvaayaa.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/OhOhEthanaiAzhagu_AdheyKaNgaL.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/HasiliFasili_Aadhavan.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/GermanyinSenthen_UllaasaParavaigaL.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/EnnulleEnnulle_Valli.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/EnnamoEdho_Ko.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/EnnaSaththam_PunnagaiMannan.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/endhan-nenjil.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/ElangaathuVeesudhe_PithAmagan.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/DolDolDhaan_Pokkiri.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/DailamoDailamo_Dishyum.htm"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/chittukkuruvi.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/chinna-mani.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/ChinnaChinnaAasai_Roja.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/AyyayyayoAanandhame_Kumki.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/anjali-anjali.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/AnjaliAnjaliAnjali_Anjali.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/AndhiMazhai_RaajaPaarvai.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/AmutheTamizhe_KovilPura.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/AmmaEndrazhaikkadha_Mannan.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/AiyyaiyoPudichirukku_Saami.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/aedho-oru-paattu.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/AedhOMOgam_KOzhiKoovudhu.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/AePaadalOndru_Priya.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/AdiyeKolludhe_VaaranamAayiram.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/AdhoAndhaParavai_AayirathilOruvan.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/AdadaMazhada_Paiyyaa.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/aayiram-thamarai.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/AarirOAaraarirO_DheivaThirumagaL.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/AnandaRaagam_PanneerPushpangaL.html"
  },
  {
    "Song_Links": "/song/tamil/karn/AadaludanPaadalai_KudiyirundhaKoyil.html"
  }
]
```

Comment: This is kind of a subjective question. You can use anything from a framework to vanilla javascript + html to achieve this.

Comment: What kind of framework is generally used ? I don't know which direction to look at. Something like Node.js , php is what is used for this ? Or is it like react angular  you are refering to ?

Comment: All of the above can be used. JSON is supported by just about anything.

Comment: This confuses me more, For a app that will be running on react native ....Can I execute it without needing node.js , php or any of those.....Just using react native , can I make this app?

Comment: Yes you can use react native.